# How to get CMenu popup menu to disappearing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, mfc

I have a popup menu for my application in the system tray. The issue I'm have is I can not get the menu to disappear without selecting an item.

**How could I get the popup menu to disappear when I click elsewhere in windows?**

Here is the code for making the popup menu appear:

```
LRESULT WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if( message == WM_MYMESSAGE && lParam == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        m_menu.CreatePopupMenu();        
        POINT point;

        GetCursorPos(&point);
        m_menu.AppendMenu(MF_POPUP, WM_MAXIMIZE, _T("Maximize"));
        m_menu.AppendMenu(MF_POPUP, WM_EXIT, _T("Exit"));
        m_menu.TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN|TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, this);

    }
    return CDialog::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I've tried using `CMenu::DestroyMenu` with no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was invoking the `SetForegroundWindow();` function before calling `TrackPopupMenu`.

I found the solution in [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the `TrackPopupMenu` function description.

Comment: If you do this, be sure to follow the rest of the code; specifically, the PostMessage(<handle to window you made the foreground window>, WM_NULL, 0, 0).

Answer (score 0):

Add TPM_RETURNCMD flag. 
With this flag the TrackPopupMenu function returns if a menu item was chosen or the user clicked outside.

```
CMenu menu;
CMenu *pSub = NULL;

// popup a menu to get the number of pages to display
VERIFY(menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MY_MENU));
pSub = menu.GetSubMenu(0);

int command = pSub->TrackPopupMenu(
        TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_RETURNCMD, 
        point.x, 
        point.y, 
        this);
```

This is working for me.

Comment: In my application I don't have a menu resource define(IDR_MY_MENU). Will I need one?

Comment: This didn't work for me but i found what did. Thanks for your help.